# Copy subdirectories using goroutines

Tags: go

My program copies multiple files and directories from different parts of the computer to one place.

One of the directories is very big, so it takes about 20-30 seconds to copy it. For now I just made this method which copies that directory to start as a goroutine:

```
func CopySpecificDirectory(source, dest string, quit chan int) (err error) {
    files, err := os.Open(source)
    file, err := files.Readdir(0)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error reading directory %s: %s\n", source, err)
        return err
    }

    for _, f := range file {
        if f.IsDir() {
            copy.CopyDir(source+"\\"+f.Name(), dest+"\\"+f.Name())
        } else {
            copy.CopyFile(source+"\\"+f.Name(), dest+"\\"+f.Name())
        }
    }

    quit <- 1

    return nil
}
```

Main:

```
quit := make(chan int)
go CopySpecificDirectory(config.Location+"\\Directory", config.Destination, quit)
```

This just improves my program by a few seconds. Inside my CopySpecificDirectory method (if this is the best way) I want for each directory to create a goroutine, something like this maybe:

```
c := make(chan int)
for _, f := range file {
    if f.IsDir() {
        go func() {
            copy.CopyDir(source+"\\"+f.Name(), dest+"\\"+f.Name())
            c <- 1
        }()
    } else {
        copy.CopyFile(source+"\\"+f.Name(), dest+"\\"+f.Name())
    }
}
```

With this approach I don't know where to wait for the copy to finish for every directory (<- c).
Is this the best way ? If anyone has other suggestion what is the fastest way to copy a directory, I will love to hear it.

edit:

I used the aproach form the example of sync.WaitGroup from the website.

```
for _, f := range file {
    if f.IsDir() {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            copy.CopyDir(source+"\\"+f.Name(), dest+"\\"+f.Name())
        }()
    // more code
```

I have declared `var wg sync.WaitGroup` as global, and I do `wg.Wait()` in main right after I call `CopySpecificDirectory`.

But `CopySpecificDirectory` finishes before copying all the contents. What am I doing wrong ? Looks like it is not waiting for the goroutines to finish.

Comment: config.Location+"\\Directory" will only work on windows. But filepath.Join(config.Location, "Directory") will work anywhere. Just use path/filepath package.

Comment: That doesn't seem wise to me. Copying files require a lot of I/O and doing in parallel on the same set of drives should not really improve anything much. Actually, it could go the other way where the head has to be moved dramatically between files of the same folder and that would take longer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`sync.WaitGroup()`](http://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup) instead of channels:

1. Create a wait group object.
2. Before spawning a goroutine, `Add()` one to it.
3. When a goroutine is about to quit, it calls `Done()` on that object.
4. In your main (waiting) code, call `Wait()` on that object. This function will return once all the goroutines "tracked" this way finish their execution.

---

Note that your program is I/O bound, not CPU-bound.  You *could* save some time if your code would need to copy files from *physically different* devices to (other) physically different devices. If you're just shuffling files around on the same filesystem, or all your sources are on the same filesystem, or all your destinations are on the same filesystem, you won't gain much as your goroutines would just compete over the single shared resource—the storage device—and the end result won't be much more different from the case when you were just executing copying operations sequentially.

To provide an example, the manual page for the `/etc/fstab` file which contains information on mounted/mountable filesystems on classic Unix systems mentions that the OS never checks filesystems located on the same physical medium at the same time—only sequentially, while at the same time it would check filesystems located on different drives in parallel.  See the entry for the `fs_passno` parameter in the [manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/fstab).

Comment: I have edit the question. Looks like it doesn't wait for the goroutines to finish.

Comment: @vBx, `wg.Wait()` does not wait for goroutines--it waits for the counter in `wg` to come down to zero.  So, either you forget to increment it by one before running at least one of your goroutines or somehow you manage to do `wg.Wait()` *concurrently* with the code which fires up your goroutines--then that could create a legitimate situation when at the time the `wg.Wait()` call is entered, `wg` is *yet* at 0 and hence `Wait()` returns immediately.

Comment: Just like in the code I posted, first I do Add(1) before starting a goroutine, so that should not be a problem, I guess. And I do wait in main() which is not concurent. Kinda confuse what the problem is here :)

Comment: @vBx, care to post the full example at some pastebin site or play.golang.org?

Comment: For those interested: [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/rk3tI1kN5PA/QY66cKPz9psJ) is a thread on `golang-nuts` which deals with the rest of the problem.

Comment: posting a corrected sample code is what you need to provide to us visiting SO

Answer (score 1):

> With this approach I don't know where to wait for the copy to finish for every directory (<- c).

Instead of signaling on a channel, you could use [SyncGroup](http://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup) to coordinate all your goroutines. You call `wg.Add(1)` for each spawned goroutine and make them call `wg.Done()` when they're, well, done. Then you do `wg.Wait()` after spawning all of them to wait until they all finish.

As for how to speed up copying in general, there is no definite answer. It depends on a lot of factors (OS probably, filesystem, hard disk, load, etc.).

Comment: I used your suggestion, but it doesn't wait for the goroutines to finish. I have edit the question with my approach.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to both @kostix and @justinas for helping out. I follow their solution, the only problem still left was that inside my for loop f doesn't bind necessarily until after the loop completes.

So I had to add `f := f`. This works now:

```
for _, f := range file {
    f := f
    if f.IsDir() {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            copy.CopyDir(source+"\\"+f.Name(), dest+"\\"+f.Name())
            defer wg.Done()
        }()
    } else {
        copy.CopyFile(source+"\\"+f.Name(), dest+"\\"+f.Name())
    }
}
```